# Program That Teaches Someone Multiplication with Random Numbers

Tags: java

I am writing a program (game) that teaches someone multiplication. In this program, random pair of numbers are to be generated and inserted into the question: "What is x * y = z?" If the person answers correctly, then the system will print out "Very Good!" If the person does not answer the question correctly, then the system will print out, "No. Please try again." (Which, in return, the program will continue to ask the question until the person answers the question correctly.) As the person answers the question correctly, a new method will generate another question for the person to answer.

My code is breaking at the variable "answer" and the if statement "(guess != answer)."

Here is my code:

```
 public class Exercise_535 {

     public class Multiply{
         SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

         int answer;
     }

     public void Quiz() {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int guess;

         System.out.println("Enter your answer: ");
         guess = input.nextInt();

         while(guess != -1)
                 {
                     checkResponse(guess);

                     System.out.println("Enter your answer: ");
                     guess = input.nextInt();  
                 }

     }

     public void createQuestion(){

         SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();

         int digit1 = randomNumbers.nextInt();
         int digit2 = randomNumbers.nextInt();

         answer = digit1 * digit2;

         System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d\n", digit1, digit2);

     }

     public void checkResponse(){

     if (guess != answer)

         System.out.println("No. Please try again.");

     else{
         System.out.print("Very Good!");

         createQuestion();
     }


 }

 }
```

Is there anyone that is able to help, or at least point me in the correct direction?

Thanks.

Comment: "My code is breaking." doesn't tell us (and potential reader with similar problem) much about your problem. You need to explain *how* it is breaking.

Comment: I have added my edits to answer your question.

Comment: Your variables are out of scope. You probably want to read up on variable scope in java. Here's a link I found from Google: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Comment: It's hard to get a view of your entry points. I don't ever see `createQuestion` getting called, so it's hard to tell where things go wrong. It may be as @Crollster proposed, because variable scope is important.

Comment: I suppose that is the question. I am not understanding fully how to create the variable scopes.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand the scope of variables.  In java if you create a variable (where you say int guess or int answer) that variable only lives within whatever curly braces you put it in -> { }.  So if you need that variable in another method, you need to pass it that variable in the parentheses. checkResponse() doesn't know what guess or answer are, because they aren't declared in that scope, and you don't pass them in at the start of the function (you could have checkResponse(int guess, int answer) and then pass those in when you call it, for example).

You have an inner class Multiply, is there a reason you created a class within a class?  There are reasons to do that, but it doesn't seem like you have any reason to do that here.

Also I don't see a main function, which is the entry point to a Java program, and all other functions need to be called from there (so Main() could then call Quiz() in your case, which would then call your other two functions).  Computers read programs one line at a time, and when you call a function/method (like Quiz()) it jumps to that part, and then returns when that function calls "return".

I know this is a lot of information, but it doesn't seem like you understand  how Java programs flow.  What are you using to study Java?  If you are reading a book or doing a course, I recommend reviewing some of the earlier lessons, to understand the flow of the program better.  It is difficult for people to answer your question because the way your code is set up doesn't have a logical flow (which is why it isn't working).  Hope this helps a little.