# Computer-Assisted Instruction (CAI) for Teaching Someone Math

Tags: java

I am writing a program (game) that teaches someone multiplication. In this program, random pair of numbers are to be generated and inserted into the question: "What is x * y = z?" If the person answers correctly, then the system will print out "Very Good!" If the person does not answer the question correctly, then the system will print out, "No. Please try again." (Which, in return, the program will continue to ask the question until the person answers the question correctly.) As the person answers the question correctly, a new method will generate another question for the person to answer.

When I run the program it says "successful build;" however, there are no questions being asked. (In other words, nothing prints out.)

Here is  the code:

```
 package exercise_5.pkg35;

 import java.security.SecureRandom;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Exercise_535 {

 private static int answer;
 private static int guess;
 private static int checkReponse;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         int answer;

     }

     public void Quiz(){
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int guess;
     }

     public void createQuestion(){

         SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
         int number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt();
         int number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt();

         answer = number1 * number2;

         System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d\n", number1, number2);
     }

     public void checkResponse(){

         if (guess != answer)

             System.out.println("No. Please try again.");

         else{

             System.out.println("Very Good!");
                     createQuestion(); 
         }

     }

 }
```

Can anyone tell me why nothing is being printed out?

Comment: You don't have anything in your main method.

Comment: It sounds like you're compiling the program and then not actually running it.

Comment: Is this class supposed to have an empty constructor? your main method only declares an int. you have to tell Java to start running all the functions in the class.

Comment: @chrylis: with that `main` method, there is not much to run anyway...

Comment: When a Java class i run it runs the `public static void main` method. In your main method you declare a variable. Nothing else in there so you can't expect it to do much more. Perhaps you need to create an instance and call some of your methods? Perhaps debug a little?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is being printed out here because you have nothing in your `main` method. This is the method that is called when you run your program, from there you can call all the other methods to be run.

For example if you had something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SecureRandom randomNumbers = new SecureRandom();
    int number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt();
    int number2 = randomNumbers.nextInt();

    answer = number1 * number2;

    System.out.printf("How much is %d times %d\n", number1, number2);
}
```

That would ask the user what the question: How much is `number1` * `number2`. From here you would have to save the value the user entered and determine if it's correct (with other methods if you'd like or just all in main).

Comment: Please don't give the answer fully away, since this is obviously homework. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, [you already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571582/program-that-teaches-someone-multiplication-with-random-numbers), so the same answer. A *Java* program always starts at the **`main`**. You specify:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int answer;
 }
```

So it means you ask Java to declare an `int`:

```
    int answer;
```

And do nothing with it, later you terminate. You must give **the main instructions so it has some reason to print something**.

Since this is homework, I think one better does not provide a *solution* to solve the problem...

Answer (score 1):

As CommuSoft said, production of code is your assignment so I won't give you answers just ideas. You need to insert a while loop within the main loop that contains your methods you have created. Main method runs the program. Also, you will get an error with your input because your scanner is declared in Quiz. Declare the scanner at the same time you do answer and guess.